# How to use socket.IO client type definitions for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, socket.io, typescript-typings

I have installed the Typescript definitions for a SocketIO client using

```
npm install @types/socket.io-client
```

But in VS Code I still get type errors:

```
let socket: SocketIOClientStatic = io()
```

> Type 'Socket' is missing the following properties from type 'SocketIOClientStatic': protocol, Socket, Manager, managersts(2739)

All these properties are not mentioned as options in intellisense, or in he socketIO docs... they shouldn't be needed when creating an `io()`

How can I use Typescript with the SocketIO client?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `io` function has return type `SocketIOClient.Socket` and not `SocketIOClientStatic`. If you use that type, or leave out the signature altogether, it works as expected:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io('http://localhost');
const anotherSocket = io('http://localhost');
```

Answer (score 7):

On client version 4.x

```
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to extend the answer of Oblosys:

If the `esModuleInterop` flag is active and you get an error message like

> This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used
> with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.

then do the import with the `as`-Syntax:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket: SocketIOClient.Socket = io('http://localhost');
```