# Where is 'emit' for IO in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, socket.io

I am using socket.io on a node.js application and it appears to be missing the 'emit' call.

For the @types, I am using @types/socket.io

Importing :

```
import io from 'socket.io';
```

Trying to use 'io.emit' gives this error:

```
Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'SocketIOStatic'.ts(2339)
```

How can I import io so all the calls like 'emit' and 'sockets' is available?

Comment: Show us your code where you're attempting to use `io.emit`

Comment: There is no code because it won't accept 'emit', so I can't get past that. But you could suppose something like 'io.emit('message', "Hello There");'

Comment: There's a code example [here](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/#Emitting-events).  Try that and see if it works.  If you can't get it to work, edit this question to include the code that you tried that didn't work.

Comment: This reminds me of a socket.io question I answered last year. Maybe that answer is helpful for you as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189736/how-to-use-socket-io-client-type-definitions-for-typescript/57190894#57190894

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. I thought IO was a singleton. But it's not. I just needed to instantiate it as an object and use that object to make the calls. Thanks for the guidance.